# Edit PFRelation of unsaved PFObject

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have a PFObject subclass called X, and I wish to send it to the cloud **only when I'm *done* editing its properties.** The user might quit the app before finishing editing its properties, so X shouldn't be sent to the cloud.

X contains a PFRelation (many-to-many) to Y (also a subclass of PFObject).
I created a UIViewController that lets the user edit this relation.
on viewDidLoad I try to get the Ys out of X:

```
PFQuery *yRelationQuery = [self.x.ys query];
    [yRelationQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    }];
```

but Parse always complains "Tried to save an object with a new, unsaved child." First, let's start by saying that this snipped shouldn't save anything, so I'm not sure why Parse complains of saving.
Second, I read enough to understand that PFRelation only works on saved objects. but I really, really don't want to send X to the cloud until the user is done with it. What I try to do here is that when the user is done with the object, and presses "save", the x object should be sent online. What alternative do I have to make this possible?

Thank you so much for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use NSUserdefault in viewWillDisappear, and saving the object locally. And have the save to parse in the buttons save function.

To save:
NSString *valueToSave = @"someValue";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"preferenceName"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

And to load:

NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Sure, I could just save the Ys separately in an array, but I wanted pretty way to do that so I could save the PFObject in a single save method. If I save the Ys separately in memory, I'll have to save PFObject twice. First so I could alter PFRelation (since before saving it doesn't let me), and then save it once more to save the new relation. I find this tedious and want a better solution. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Even though your relational object is associated with the other, "parent" object, you can still work on it separately. Here's what I would do:

1. Create your X object. Save it whenever you are ready since it should belong to its own Parse class anyway.
2. In the `saveInBackground` block of your X object, point Y to it and save Y.

Below is an example in Swift (sorry, I stopped using Objective-C):

```
let X = PFObject(className: "X")
let Y = PFObject(className: "Y")

X["stuff"] = "value"

//Save X
X.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{ (success, error) -> Void in
  if success {
    Y["xRelation"] = X

    //We know X is ready, so save Y now
    Y.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why the snipped I attached crashes. Parse complains I try to save an object with an unsaved child, yet I didn't write any save command. Is it truly impossible to add objects to relation without uploading them to the cloud first?